# can we install WordPress plugins in custom website?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, backend

I just wanted to know that can we use WordPress plugins on the custom website. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress plugin used WordPress functionality...so you can't use it without core.

Answer (score 0):

If by "custom website" you mean a non WordPress site then the answer would be no. The issue is that WordPress plugins and themes rely on a variety of actions, filters and functions that are specific to WordPress and would not be present in a site that is not built using WordPress.

Comment: thanks bill, but I met a person who said that we can use WP plugins on a live server.
but he didn't tell me more.